# moderncv - hompage link in 2 lines

Tags: moderncv

is it possible to put the homepage link in the moderncv header in 2 lines, as it doesn't look nice if it is one line, whereas all the other personal data entries are quite small.

Thankful for any help - it isn't working with `\\`
or `\newline`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\homepage{www.thejohnandjanedoefamily.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: As Kurt says, this really does not seem to make sense as it stands. I'm therefore closing: request reopening if you have more info.